# Codeigniter Unable to get views data array for my controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why i cant get my array data from views into my controller?

Views:

```
                                    <?php
                                foreach($get_q->result() as $gq){
                                ?>
                                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $gq->id;  ?>" name="hidden" type="hidden">

                                <?php 
                                }
                                ?>
```

Controller

```
   if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)  
       {  
            //true  
            $this->load->model("mymodel");  
           for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post('hidden')); $i++){
           $data = array(  
                'question_id' => $this->input->post("hidden")[$i]
            ); 

           if($this->input->post("insert"))  
            {  
                $this->mymodel->my_function($data);   
            }  
            }  

       }
```

Its working but its only get the last element of the array the other element becomes zero(0).

Like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name="hidden"` is incorrect. Multiple `name="hidden"` means that the last field overwrites all previous values. Use `[]` notation:

```
<input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $gq->id;  ?>" name="hidden[]" type="hidden">
                                                             ----- NOTE ^
```

With this, `$this->input->post('hidden')` will be **array**, as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for answering my problem, but sadly it didn't work. I got same problem after doing name="hidden[<?php echo $i ?>]"

Comment: What is `$i`? Next - `print_r($this->input->post('hidden'))` and __see what is there__.

Comment: $i is my iteration for my foreach loop, and by the way i already solve my problem by initializing new array to insert my data. This name="hidden[]" really helps thanks alot sir! Godbless :)